# Bootstrap 3 with respond.js and html5shiv.js still not working on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-3, html5shiv, respond.js

I have a website which is running Bootstrap 3 and working perfectly on all browsers except IE8. It's the problem where the media queries aren't supported, so the content stretches as if it was run on a mobile device.

I have tried including respond.js, html5shiv.js and the html5shim from Google. Also the meta http-equiv-tag is included. The media queries still don't seem to work.

Also, I know respond.js doesn't work locally because of it's xmlHttpRequest-thingy, but this site is running on a webserver.

I've also made sure both respond.js and html5shiv.js are found and the links are not broken.

Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. Had to include a non-responsive css file as well. Will post accepted answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so the non-responsive css file wasn't exactly what we were looking for. However, we found the problem:

IE8 doesn't seem to like the @import-property.

We used a global css file which imported the necessary styles. When moving all stylesheets to the header and including them with a normal link-tag, it works.

It's weird though, the regular bootstrap styling (buttons, backgrounds and such) got imported properly. The grid system was not. I guess Internet Explorer works in mysterious and retarded ways.

Comment: That was my Problem as well. After I added all styles in application.css.scss via asset pipeline (I am using rails) *= require style.css it worked perfectly. Thanks for the heads up!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case it was the QUIRKS mode that messed it up. IE can be forced to go into Quirks mode by replacing the standard (Bootstrap 3.0 suggested):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Don't ever revert to html4, are you crazy?

Comment: you're right. A Different version might be more suitable. This did fix the problem though... better make it html5

Comment: You've saved my life!
I still wonder how Microsoft could release such a piece of software.

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure that you load the following scripts *after* loading jQuery.

Especially in WordPress and other frameworks some people tend to include jQuery just before the closing  tag and therefore after the html5shiv.js and respond.js script, which causes issues in IE8

```
<!-- Include first -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modern-business.js"></script>
     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->  
    </head>
```

if you want to try in local...try through localhost, or create a QA server and set the content and try.
we need respond.js for bootstrap 3 and it wont work in local machine if we just put it in js and append it to html in header.
It will say access denied.
it works only through server as ie have security restriction.
:P