# Twitter Bootstrap examples not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I'm having some problems getting the Twitter Bootstrap examples to work in IE8 on my own site. I've made an exact copy of this page (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/). The example page on getbootstrap.com works great in IE7-9. The page on my server doesn't work at all? I think the problem is Respond.js isn't working? (http://www.davekz.com/_twbs.html) I'm completely stumped. Anyone have any thoughts. I've tried another server too (highly unlikely the cause of the problem).

Comment: See if one of these answers help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19708748/1004312

Comment: See updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The copy of your bootstrap CSS must be hosted locally, the CDN stuff does not.

http://app.crossbrowsertesting.com/public/i82cbc31d6d6bc2e/livetests/1245371/snapshots/zc8cbc63e8e0c6b6fce2

Also, your justified-nav.css appears to be an html file when I click on it on view source.

Copy of same file, same problems until I hosted the css directly.

http://badasstheme.com/test-justified.html

> BOOTSTRAP'S DOCS:
>
> **Respond.js and cross-domain CSS**
>
> Using Respond.js with CSS hosted on a different (sub)domain (for
>   example, on a CDN) requires some additional setup. See the Respond.js
>   docs for details.

Comment: Formatting matches exactly now (copy/pasta direct form getboostrap). Still nothing.

Comment: i'm going to copy this to my server. Will get back to you. Putting the respond.js outside the conditional comments and see if you get any errors in IE8 or some kind of feedback from that shitty browser.